# How can I find sentences nested deeper than one bracket '()' set?

Tags: regex, perl

I want to print sentences from text file placed in `()` brackets deeper than one pair of brackets.

For example for this text file :

```
blabla(nothing(print me)) nanana (nanan)
blablabla(aaaaaaa(eeee(bbbb(cccc)bbb))aa)
blabla (blabla(hhhhh))
```

the output should be :

```
print me
eeee(bbbb(cccc)bbb)
bbbb(cccc)bbb
cccc
hhhhh
```

This is what I've done so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w

open(FILE, "<", $ARGV[0]) or die "file open error";

if ( @ARGV ) #if there are args
{
    if ( -f $ARGV[0] ) #if its regular file
    {
      while(<FILE>)
      {
        my @array =  split('\)',$_);
        foreach(@array)
        {
          if ($_ =~ /.*\((.*)/) 
          {
            print "$1\n";
          }
        }
      }
    close(FILE);
}
else{
print "Arg is not a file\n";}
}
else{
print "no args\n";}
```

My code can't separate the sentences placed in deeper brackets.

Comment: FYI, this has nothing to do with Ubuntu. Perl's regular expressions are consistent (at least for a given version of Perl) across all operating systems.

Comment: I just typed Ubuntu in the title for the information what system I am using. Sorry for misleading :)

Comment: @Piodo No need to apologize. It's usually better to give too much information than not enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming brackets are balanced:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @a;

while (<DATA>) {
    while (/\(([^()]*(?:\(((?1))\)[^()]*(?{push @a, $2}))*+)\)/g){}
}

print join "\n", @a;

__DATA__
blabla(nothing(print me)) nanana (nanan)
blablabla(aaaaaaa(eeee(bbbb(cccc)bb(xxxx)b))aa)
blabla (blabla(hhhhh))
```

It returns:

```
print me
cccc
xxxx
bbbb(cccc)bb(xxxx)b
eeee(bbbb(cccc)bb(xxxx)b)
hhhhh
```

The idea is to store the capture group 2 content after each recursion, using the `(?{...})` construct to execute code in the pattern.

Note that the order of results isn't ideal since the innermost content appears first. Unfortunately, I didn't find a way to change the order of results.

Pattern details:

```
\(  # opening bracket level 1
(   # open capture group 1
    [^()]*        # all that is not a bracket
    (?:
        \(        # opening bracket for level 2 (or more when a recursion occurs)
        (         # capture group 2: to store the result
            (?1)  # recursion
        )
        \)        # closing bracket for level 2 (or more ...)
        [^()]*    # 
        (?{push @a, $2}) # store the capture group 2 content in @a
    )*+ # repeat when needed
)
\) # closing bracket level 1
```

---

EDIT: This pattern assumes that brackets are balanced, but if it isn't the case, this may cause problems of unwanted results for certain strings. The reason is that results are stored before the whole pattern succeeds.

Example with the string `1234 ( 5678 (abcd(efgh)ijkl)` where a closing bracket is missing:

```
1234 ( 5678 (abcd(efgh)ijkl)
#    ^      ^---- second attempt succeeds, "efgh" is stored
#    '---- first attempt fails, but "efgh", "abcd(efgh)ijkl" are stored
```

To solve the problem, you can choose between two default behaviours:

- the strict behaviour that only accepts balanced brackets. All you need is to store the results in a temporary array and to reset this array in the while loop or when a closing bracket is missing. In this case the result will only be `"efgh"`:

```
my @a;
my @b;

while (<DATA>) {
    while (/\(([^()]*(?:\(((?1))\)[^()]*(?{push @b, $2}))*+)(?:\)|(?{undef @b})(*F))/g) {
        push @a, @b;
        undef @b;
    }
}
```

- a more tolerant behaviour that doesn't make mandatory the closing bracket. To do that you must replace each `\)` with `(?:\)|$)`. In this case, the first attempt succeeds and consumes characters until the end of the string (in other words, there isn't a second attempt). The results are `"efgh"` and `"abcd(efgh)ijkl"`

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Indeed, I am actually searching how to use a `?{ }` construct or to build a pattern with `\G` and a lookahead to get nested results.

Comment: Good job ! This is very well done. The code is really short I am impressed with that. However I've found not serious bug. If the input has some bigger level of brackets the code sometimes dubles the results. For example for input :    `nanana((print 2) (print 3 (print4(print5)) )` , there are `print5` doubled in results. Its not a serious problem so If you dont want to check it it's no problem, I am fine with your code in this form :)

Comment: @Piodo: I have found the problem and will post an edit as soon as possible. The problem is that results are stored before the full pattern succeeds, so in your example where the brackets aren't balanced, results from the failing attempt at the first opening bracket position are stored, this position fails (cause the missing closing bracket), and then an other attempts at the third opening bracket gives results too. That's the reason you obtain duplicate items.

Answer (score 2):

This is probably easiest, and the most maintainable with a two-pass solution.

The initial pass captures all first level parentheses.  The second pass captures all enclosed parenthesis groups, only advancing a single character in order to match every level of embedded paren groups:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use v5.10;

my $data = do { local $/; <DATA> };

my $parens_content_re = qr{
    \(
        (
            (?:
                [^()]*+
                |
                \( (?1) \)
            )*
        )
    \)
}x;

say for map {/(?=$parens_content_re)\(/g} map {/$parens_content_re/g} $data;

__DATA__
blabla(nothing(print me)) nanana (nanan)
blablabla(aaaaaaa(eeee(bbbb(cccc)bbb))aa)
blabla (blabla(hhhhh))
----(----(aaaa(123)bbbb(456)cccc)----)----
```

Outputs:

```
$ perl parens.pl
print me
eeee(bbbb(cccc)bbb)
bbbb(cccc)bbb
cccc
hhhhh
aaaa(123)bbbb(456)cccc
123
456
```

Comment: It stops to work with consecutive nested brackets, for example with: `----(----(aaaa(123)bbbb(456)cccc)----)----`, you will never get `456`. *(I tried this kind of ways before)*

Comment: @CasimiretHippolyte Yep, that's true.  Was mostly going for a proof of concept with the data he provided, then a fully bullet proof solution.  However, I went ahead and adjust the approach to cover your extra use case.

Comment: If you find that I will kiss your feet.

Answer (score 2):

This code works by capturing levels recursively, using a simple regex for `)` and `split`-ing by `(` for the opening paren.  It first prepares by peeling off the two starting layers of nesting. It works for shown examples, and a few others.  However, there are other ways to nest pairs, for which rules are not specified. Also, this is probably rough around the edges. There is no magic of any kind involved and adjusting code for new cases should be feasible.

```
use warnings; 
use strict; 

my ($lev, @el, @res, $rret); 
while (my $str = <DATA>) 
{ 
    print "\nString: $str\n"; 
    @res = (); 

    # Drop two layers to start: strip last two ), split by ( and drop 0,1 
    $str =~ s/ (.*) \) [^)]* \) [^)]* $/$1/x; 
    @el = split '\(', $str; 
    @el = @el[2..$#el]; 
    # Edge case: may have one element and be done, but with extra ) 
    if (@el > 1) { $lev = join '(', @el }
    else         { ($lev = $el[0]) =~ s|\)||g } 
    push @res, $lev; 

    # Get next level and join string back, recursively 
    while ( $rret = nest_one($lev) ) {  
        $lev = join '(', @$rret; 
        push @res, $lev; 
        last if @$rret == 1; 
    } 

    print "\t$_\n" for @res; 
} 

# Strip last ) and past it, split by ( and drop first element 
sub nest_one { 
    (my $lev = $_[0]) =~ s/(.*) \) [^)]* $/$1/x; 
    my @el = split '\(', $lev; 
    shift @el; 
    return (@el) ? \@el : undef; 
} 

__DATA__ 
blabla(nothing(print me)) nanana (nanan) 
blablabla(aaaaaaa(eeee(bbbb(cccc)bbb))aa) 
blabla (blabla(hhhhh))
```

It prints

```
blabla(nothing(print me)) nanana (nanan)

        print me

blablabla(aaaaaaa(eeee(bbbb(cccc)bbb))aa)

        eeee(bbbb(cccc)bbb)
        bbbb(cccc)bbb
        cccc

blabla (blabla(hhhhh))

        hhhhh
```